# How to show the "loading spinner" every time a new ajax call is made with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I want to show the loading icon/image every time an ajax call is executing. **In my case, my code, the image is showing once, and that's it**. Even there are multiple ajax call in a for loop, the image is showing once, and disappearing on the first success state of the first ajax call.

This is my code:

```
function ajaxCall(ajaxObject){ 
     $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'url/' + ajaxObject,

        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#someid").LoadingOverlay("show");
        },
        success: function (imagesList) {
            showGenerated(imagesList);
        },
        complete:function(){
            $("#someid").LoadingOverlay("hide", true);

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error imaging processing');
        }
    });
} 
jsObject = JSON.parse(listImages.attr("data-images"));

    for (i = 0; i < jsObject.length; i++) {
        ajaxCall(jsObject[i].filesID);
    }
```

I also tried using `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){}).ajaxStop(function(){});` but **the result is the same**, **the "loading spinner" shows only once**, and disappear when ALL THE AJAX CALLS ARE COMPLETED...

The network tab in chrome debugging is showing multiple ajax get requests, so there are more ajax calls, but the spinner/loading is appearing as though it were just one ajax call.

**So I want the image to appear and disappear every time a new ajax call is made.**

Comment: Record a count of how many times `beforeSend:` is hit and now many times `complete:` is hit - within `complete:` only hide it if it's zero.

Comment: Alternatively: Append/Remove a new loading overlay for each call rather than show/hide a single one.

Comment: You're making `jsObject.length` calls in rapid succession. Before each, a call is made to show the spinner. However, a previous ajax call might have just finished and has hidden the spinner. Since all of this may occur over a period of milliseconds, you might not even see the show/hide occur.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the issue is that there are a number of ajax calls made at the same time - whether in a loop or one-after-the-other is irrelevant - it's highly unlikely (impossible even as js is single-threaded) that the `complete:` will be called before the next `beforeSend:` but as soon as the first has completed it hides the loader.

Comment: @freedomn-m JavaScript is indeed single-threaded, but that doesn't mean things can't happen out of order due to the asynchronicity of ajax. There are several dozen questions on SO about how to get ajax requests to occur in order rather than seemingly at random for that reason.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, it's a tricky problem.  But if you have a `for` loop, that loop must complete before the javascript runtime can handle/process any ajax response.  Asynchronous code can't "interupt" running code, it just runs later.  (which is also why it's so easy to 'lock' the UI)

Comment: @freedomn-m Okay, I think we're talking past each other here. I'm not talking about anything getting blocked. What I was failing to see was that all of the `beforeSend` calls are called within the loop, but `complete` could be called outside of the loop. That's why the spinner hides as soon as the first ajax call completes.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey yes, maybe all happens too fast is there other way? practically all the software is a backend php image resize + front end ajax, and the software must take one image at a time resize it with php and send a json to js, and then another ajax call is made, again resize...till the image list is finished. Is there a way to make a time gap between the ajax calls?

Comment: @freedomn-m both beforeSend and complete: are equal time hit, the number of images in the list, so the loop length 30 times in my app test.

Comment: Of course send/complete are hit equal times, they're a pair.  They're all pushed at the same time so if you add a console.log you'll see 30x send then 30x complete over time.  So essentially you do this:  `$("#loading").show().show().show().show().hide().hide().hide().hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it for every ajax call, on ajax call you need to show and after getting the response hiding it, like what you are doing now.

other possibility is you need to add that one as globally with these followed ajax  functions **ajaxStart** and **ajaxStop**

```
$('#loading-image').bind('ajaxStart',
 function(){
$(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop',function(){
$(this).hide();});
```

You can find the documentation here [AjaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

Comment: tried this `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#list").LoadingOverlay("show", {
        image       : "",
        fontawesome : "fa fa-cog fa-spin"
    });
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $("#list").LoadingOverlay("hide", true);
});` but will only show the spinning until all the request are done. Maybe as @HereticMonkey said it all hapends too fast to see the gap, appear /disappear of the spining/loading image...

Comment: Note: [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) was deprecated in version 3.0 of jQuery.